# Can Azure AD B2C be configured to use GSuite (Google org-own) as an IdP?

Tags: saml, azure-ad-b2c, google-workspace

Azure AD B2C has the concept of Custom Policies, which in theory can be used to connect a B2C tenant to any IdP using SAML (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom).

Google's GSuite (org-owned) system can apparently be connected to as an IdP using SAML (only SAML) (see https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en).

Has anyone successfully connected these so that end users could use their GSuite accounts to authenticate to enterprise application with Azure AD B2C in the middle?

thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 1):

B2C supports SAML and through custom policies you can connect to other services and return identities although I have only done this with OIDC as the SAML meta data may be an issue.

A good article here on connecting to SalesForce with SAML is here , so you should be able to change SalesForce for G Suite

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-sf-app-custom